# Looping to clear all numbers colors in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this working function to change all children button color on click.
Now im doing a "ClearGame" button, to change all button background color to its original state '#ADC0C4'. How can i do that with key or id from the children?

```
 const newBet: React.FC = () => {

  const clearGame = () => {
    let spliceRangeJSON = gamesJson[whichLoteriaIsVar].range;
    totalNumbers.splice(0, spliceRangeJSON);
    for (let i = 0; i <= spliceRangeJSON; i++) {
//Looping to change the backgroundColor using Id or Key
    }
  };

      const NumbersParent = (props: any) => {
        const [numbersColor, setNumbersColor] = useState('#ADC0C4');

        const changeButtonColor = () => {
          if (numbersColor === '#ADC0C4') {
            setNumbersColor(gamesJson[whichLoteriaIsVar].color);
            totalNumbers.push(props.id);
          } else {
            setNumbersColor('#ADC0C4');
            let searchTotalNumbers = totalNumbers.indexOf(props.id);
            totalNumbers.splice(searchTotalNumbers, 1);
          }
        };

        return (
          <Numbers style={{ backgroundColor: numbersColor }} onClick={changeButtonColor}>
            {props.children}
          </Numbers>
        );
      };

      return (
          <NumbersContainer>
            {numbersList.map((num) => (
              <NumbersParent key={num} id={num}>
                {formatNumber(num)}
              </NumbersParent>
            ))}
          </NumbersContainer>
          <ClearGame onClick{clearGame}>Clear Game</ClearGame >
      );
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to modify the state of children from the parent component,

1. Create a State Object in the parent.
2. Pass it to the children as prop
3. You can change it on clear.

Or try something like [`recoil`](https://recoiljs.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Move the useState and changeButtonColor method to the parent component and make some changes:

```
const [numbersColor, setNumbersColor] = useState({});

const changeButtonColor = (color) => {
  if (!numbersColor[color] || numbersColor[color] === '#ADC0C4') {
    setNumbersColor({...numbersColors,
      [color]: gamesJson[whichLoteriaIsVar].color
    });
    totalNumbers.push(props.id);
  } else {
    setNumbersColor({...numbersColors,
      [color]: '#ADC0C4'
    });
    let searchTotalNumbers = totalNumbers.indexOf(props.id);
    totalNumbers.splice(searchTotalNumbers, 1);
  }
};
```

Change the map to that:

```
<NumbersContainer>
  {numbersList.map((num, index) => (
    <NumbersParent key={num} id={num} index={index} changeButtonColor={(color) => {changeButtonColor(color)}}>
      {formatNumber(num)}
    </NumbersParent>
  ))}
</NumbersContainer>
```

And on the return of NumbersParent component changes to be like that:

```
<Numbers style={{ backgroundColor: numbersColor[`color${props.index}`] }} onClick={props.changeButtonColor(`color${props.index}`)}>
  {props.children}
</Numbers>
```

Finally, change clearGame function like this:

```
const clearGame = () => {
  let spliceRangeJSON = gamesJson[whichLoteriaIsVar].range;
  for (let i = 0; i <= spliceRangeJSON; i++) {
    changeButtonColor(`color${i}`)
  }
  totalNumbers.splice(0, spliceRangeJSON);
};
```

Comment: I tried, said that cant find "numbersColor" or "changeButtonColor", i edited the code

Comment: Sorry I looked very quick, now I saw the problem.